# Error on bitmap change size in some Devices

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, runtime-error

I created activity that can pick photo from gallery(with intent) and resized picked photo and putting in the button(in Drawable object )

Activity some methods:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                try{

                    if(density>=4) {//xxxdpi
                        setButtonIcon(Photos.changeSize(yourSelectedImage, 196, 196), tempButton);
                    }else if (density < 4 && density >= 3) {//xxdpi
                        setButtonIcon(Photos.changeSize(yourSelectedImage, 180, 180), tempButton);
                        Toast.makeText(context, density + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (density < 3 && density >= 2) {//xdpi
                        setButtonIcon(Photos.changeSize(yourSelectedImage,96,96), tempButton);
                        Toast.makeText(context, density + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (density < 2 && density >= 1.5) {//hdpi
                         setButtonIcon(Photos.changeSize(yourSelectedImage,72,72), tempButton);
                        Toast.makeText(context, density + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (density < 1.5 && density >= 1) {//mdpi
                         setButtonIcon(Photos.changeSize(yourSelectedImage,48,48), tempButton);
                        Toast.makeText(context, density + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (density < 1 && density >= 0.75) {//ldpi
                         setButtonIcon(Photos.changeSize(yourSelectedImage,36,36), tempButton);
                        Toast.makeText(context, density + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                      Toast.makeText(context,density+" "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
            break;

    }
}

private void setButtonIcon(Bitmap icon,DocumentButton btn) {
    Drawable draw=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),icon);
    btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, draw , null, null);
}
```

It can working in some Devices but when i tested  in Samsung Galaxy S6 (with 4.0 density) i got this error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()

This error is coming when i want to resize bitmap photo :

```
public static Bitmap changeSize(Bitmap bitmap,int newWidth,int newHeight)throws Exception{

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);

}
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: you have to resize the image to a specific height and width or dynamic ?

Comment: i cant understand your question . you check all methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem , i changed just some lines of code , i think  Cursor is my problem , in android 5 and upper ,  Cursor can not get picked image path ( path result = null)

Updated lines :

```
final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
final Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```